# How to write a dataframe to dynamodb using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'M having a Lambda function set up in AWS Cloudformation. The runtime is python3.8.
The purpose is to pull some weather data from an API and write it to DynamoDB once a day.
So far the Lambda Test on AWS checks out, all green ...but the function doesnt write any values to the dynamodb.
Is there an error in indenting maybe?

Here is the code:

```
import boto3
import pyowm
import time
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta, timezone
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   api_key = "xxxxxxx"    #Enter your own API Key
   owm = pyowm.OWM(api_key)
   city = 'Berlin, DE'

   geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='aerieous@myserver.com')
   location = geolocator.geocode(city)
   lat = location.latitude
   lon = location.longitude

   # set the date to pull the data from to yesterday
   # format = '2021-09-09 00:00:00'
   x = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1 ))
   d = x.isoformat(' ', 'seconds')

   # convert time to epoch
   p = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
   dt = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d,p)))

   url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall/timemachine?lat=%s&lon=%s&   dt=%s&appid=%s&units=metric" % (lat, lon, dt, api_key)
   response = requests.get(url)
   data_history = json.loads(response.text)

   # here we flatten only the nested list "hourly" 
   df_history2 = pd.json_normalize(data_history, record_path='hourly', meta=['lat', 'lon', 'timezone'],
                                errors='ignore')
   # convert epoch to timestamp
   df_history2['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_history2['dt'],unit='s').dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
   # replace the column header
   df_history2 = df_history2.rename(columns={'dt': 'timestamp'})
   df_history2['uuid'] = df_history2[['timestamp','timezone']].agg('-'.join, axis=1)
   df_select_hist2 = df_history2[['uuid','lat','lon', 'timezone', 'timestamp', 'temp', 'feels_like', 'humidity', 'pressure']]

   df_select_hist2 = df_select_hist2.astype(str)
   df_select_hist2

   content = df_select_hist2.to_dict('records')
   return content

   dynamodb = boto3.resource(
      'dynamodb',
      aws_access_key_id='xx',
      aws_secret_access_key='xx',
      region_name='eu-west-1')
   table = dynamodb.Table("Dev_Weather")

   for item in content:
     uuid = item['uuid']
     timezone = item['timezone']
     timestamp = item['timestamp']
     lat = item['lat']
     lon = item['lon']
     temp = item['temp']
     feels_like = item['feels_like']
     humidity = item['humidity']
     pressure = item['pressure']

     table.put_item(
        Item={
            'pk_id': uuid,
            'sk': timestamp,
            'gsi_1_pk': lat,
            'gsi_1_sk': lon,
            'gsi_2_pk': temp,
            'gsi_2_sk': feels_like,
            'humidity': humidity,
            'pressure': pressure,
            'timezone': timezone
         }
     )
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

A

Comment: print the result of the `put_item` call. See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item for the expected result.

Comment: no, that did not work either ...

Comment: Explain "did not work" please.

Comment: If I add print(response) at the end nothing is happing in the dynamodb, meaning no entries are pushed into it.

Answer (score 2):

The line `return content` ends your lambda function. It basically tells the script: I'm done and this is the result. Nothing after it is executed. Remove the line to be able to execute code afterwards. Also, the indentation in your code example seems off (a space too little when starting the dynamodb stuff),  so I'm a bit confused over why this wouldn't give syntax errors.

Also: there is no need to specify an access key, region etc. when creating the dynamodb resource. It's fetched  by lambda automatically. Just make sure the lambda role has the right permissions to call dynamodb.

Comment: Mmh, still does not work, I have removed the return statement and realigned the indents. the funny thing is: if I remove the `def lambda_handler(event, context):` and run the body in pycharm it works perfectly and populates my dynamo db. it must have something to do with how the function is called that it does not yield a result.

Comment: Without stating what the error is it's hard to debug. Did you assign the right permission to the lambda?

Comment: yes, it has a proper execution role etc. all is set up via cloudformation and the stack are up and running. its only the values, that dont get through...

Comment: Can you please state the error message when running the lambda. What does it day? Also, you also have quite some issues regarding best practices. You want to fetch the API key from secrets manager, not hard code it since it's simply a high security risk. Also, performance wise you should create the dynamodb resource outside of your lambda handler.

Comment: Ok, merci, let me refactor the code. I’ll test again and update the code here.